# How to build an apk for a Kivy app without buildozer?

Tags: python, kivy, buildozer

I want to use Kivy for my gui, but buildozer simply doesn't work for me, no matter what I tried. it's probably too buggy.
I want to target android with building an apk.
If I use another build system, will I be able to run a python host and all that's needed, or do I need to get my hands dirty and start deciphering the buildozer source code to extract what's needed?
What are your suggestions? Any ready made solutions? After all there are many python devs, and targeting android is not new.

Comment: For example, how to build an apk with gradle, but that is able to use the private.mp3 and all the kivy tricks to run a python host.

Comment: As far as I know, `buildozer` and `p4a` are the only libraries for packaging Python codes to Android apps